# One who practices art, but is the receiver and not the creator

Tags: single-word-requests

In literature, it's the *reader*. In music, it's the *listener*. In performing arts it's the *audience*, and in visual arts it's the *viewer*. What word combines these terms?

To say *audience* would be close, except it has a connotation of being very public, and thus it's not singular.

Very broadly, I would call the person an artist, but *artist* implies one who creates art.

I might call the person the *consumer*, as in "the consumer of media." This connotes art as an industry, and implies passivity.

For example, how do I complete the sentence:

> Kitsch is created by the insincere artist, but the [word] is responsible for finding value in it.

I'm looking for 1) the analogous receiver, where "If sender is to receiver, artist is to ___" and 2) a word that references the *active skill* of *consuming* art (reading, listening, etc), rather than the active skill of making art, or the passive activity of receiving without engaging and interpreting.

Comment: In your sample sentence I would use *public*, but like *audience* is not singular in meaning.

Comment: Why not *beholder* or *observer*?

Comment: This isn't an answer since I don't consider it specific enough. However I think [Patron](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=patron&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on) is very close to what you describe and is often *associated* with art:

" 5. An advocate; a defender; one that specially countenances and supports, or lends aid to advance; as patrons of the arts; a patron of useful undertakings; the patrons of virtue." [The American Dictionary of the English Language by Noah Webster 1828](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/)

Comment: Art *lover,* Art *connoisseur.*  "Art *collector*" fits your sentence but not necessarily your intent since a collector may only be in it for the money- or they may not.

Comment: The term is "patron".

Comment: @HotLicks- I think of *patron* as someone who subsidizes the arts in some way.  They make charitable donations to arts foundations etc.  They aren't just art lovers who, for example, can spend hours on a bench in a museum contemplating.

Comment: What @Jim said.

Comment: What about simply saying "practitioner"? It's not specific, but with enough context could the meaning be implied?

Comment: @cornbreadninja麵包忍者 "observer" excludes music and literature as art, although I like the slight double-meaning, the connotation of a religious observer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider ***art-lover***. It is listed in *OED* also and the earliest citation is from 1847:

> Last year was a surprise to every art lover for the crowd of excellence it produced.
>
> <sub>Fine Arts' Jrnl. 8 May 422/2</sub>

The painter *[Renoir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre-Auguste_Renoir)* once said: (mentioned in the book *The Hidden Renoir*)

> The art lover is the one to whom the medals should be given.

---

***Dilettante*** originally meant *art-lover* but it has negative connotations today. *[Vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/dilettante:)* explains as below:

> The meaning of dilettante has changed since it was borrowed from the Italian in the mid 1700s. Originally, it meant "lover of the arts," but began to take on a negative slant as the idea of doing something as a professional took hold strongly during the 18th century. A dilettante was a mere lover of art as opposed to one who did it professionally. Today, the word implies you're pretending to be more of an artist than you're interested in or capable of being, so if you call your friend who likes to paint a dilettante, it's like you're calling him or her a poser.

Comment: "*Art-lover*" is the answer, IMO. (And *amateur* is another "original" term for it, though it was not limited to the arts.)

Answer (score 2):

**Patron of the arts**

Unfortunately, I can't find a decent definition, as the all seem to devolve to *patron*, whereas *patron of the arts* is an idiom with a meaning different from it's component words.

A *patron of the arts* is a person who takes significant interest in one or more areas of art (music, painting, theater, etc) and who, particularly important for the graphic artist, is apt to purchase works of various artists.  (He/she is also apt to attend many musical presentations, theater events, etc.)  He/she may also contribute to various art-supporting organizations, but to do so is not necessary to be considered worthy of the title.

Comment: To me, *patron* nearly always has the connotation of a **sponsor**, with an economic connection. It can be an investor, a collector, or a backer. And yes, it is often someone who also appreciates art not only for its monetary value - but not always. And I would say that the monetary connection is pretty much always there. Hardly the term I would use for someone who appreciates, understands, or loves art. More the term I would use for someone who thinks s?he does those things and who is in some way interested in the $ value of art. (Not to mention that "patron" originally means boss/owner.)

Comment: Yes @Drew, that was my initial reaction. However, in consideration, patron also means customer, as in, the one who receives the service. It still feels less active than what I would like (we rarely consider skill or practice when we think of patronizing), but if we can brush aside the connotation you mentioned, this would be the correct term.

Comment: @Cameron: You're right that it can also mean customer, or even client. Still, the money association is never far. IMHO, *patron* does not mean art-lover, and vice versa.

Comment: I'm not looking for simply art-lover. I want 1) the analogous receiver, where "If sender is to receiver, artist is to ___" and 2) a word which references the active skill of *consuming* art (reading, listening, etc), rather than the active skill of *making* art. Should I put this in the original question?

Answer (score 1):

I'll go with ***connoisseur***.

> 1:  expert; especially :  one who understands the details, technique, or principles of an art and is competent to act as a critical judge
>
> 2:  one who enjoys with discrimination and appreciation of subtleties *a connoisseur of fine wines* [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/connoisseur)

Comment: *Connoisseur* is more like an expert art-lover rather than a regular one. What is the connotation in French? How do you differentiate an expert and a regular art-lover? Are there specific words or do you use phrases?

Answer (score -1):

**Perceiver** is a sense-neutral alternative.

You could also consider **enthusiast**, though you'd be edging toward tautology there.